# How to properly change Django FileField.upload_to attribute?

Tags: django, migration, storage

I'm trying to rename function used in `FileField.upload_to` attribute. After I change function name, Django fails on `Performing system checks...`. And in traceback I see 
`AttributeError: module 'the_app.models' has no attribute 'old_function_name'`.

Is it possible to change function name/replace function used in `upload_to`. And if so, how do I properly do it? Am I correct that rewriting content of old migration (applied on live server) is bad practice.

Comment: `Am I correct` - yes. Make new migration.

Comment: You need to keep any function referenced in migration files. But there's no issue renaming the function also in the old migration file, even if you already applied it. This does not affect anything in the db, so you should be fine changing it. So no, it's not necessarily bad practice. It's just "dangerous" in the sense you have to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question whether it's bad practice: It's something you need to be careful about. You definitely don't want to change anything in existing migrations that would affect the database. But Django puts quite a few things in migration files that don't affect the database. `upload_to` is one of them (`help_text` for example is also one of them).

So for changes that don't affect the db, go ahead: change them in your models and change them directly in the old migration files, it won't make any difference whether you've already applied the migration or not.